# What type of pattern should you use for CRUD when all you need is Read

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I was recently asked on a coding interview to write a simple Java console app that does some file io and displays the data. I was going to go to town with a DAO  but since I never manipulate the data past a read, the entire idea of a DAO seems overkill.

Anyone know a clean way to ensure separation of concern without the weight of full CRUD when you don't need it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like standard MVC pattern. Your console is the view, the code that reads file is the controller and the code that captures file line or whole file content is your model.
You can further simplify it as View and Model where model will encapsulate both file reading and wrapping its content into Java class.

Comment: Hmm perhaps as a view modal would not be a bad idea, place the load method in the object class and return it as a list or something on the lines of C#. So far you win, thanks for the thoughts. :)

Comment: MV does not maintain your original requirement of 'SoC', as @tsolakp says, standard MVC is the minimum pattern. Fowler's Table Gateway or Active Record appear helpful in this context.

Answer (score 1):

How about Martin Fowler's Table Gateway pattern, [explained here](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html). Just include the find (Read) methods and miss create, insert, and update.

Comment: This seems a tad much as well and only implementing the read would be the exact same as a dao with only read as well. Interesting pattern though.

Comment: I think Fowler's Table Gateway or Active Record are the minimum complexity of patterns tnat will meet your original requirement of SoC.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply refer **Command /Query pattern** ,where commands are one which perform create update and delete operation seperately and Queries are introduce to read only purpose .

hence you implement what you need and left the others

Answer (score 0):

This question was in interview so there was not much time for detailed design, As a minimum fulfillment of above concerns, following structure will provide flexibility. details could be filled as per the requirements.

```
public interface IODevice {
    String read();
    void write(String data);
}

class FileIO implements IODevice {
    @Override
    public String read() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void write(String data) {
        //...;
    }
}

class ConsoleIO implements IODevice {
    @Override
    public String read() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void write(String data) {
        //... null;
    }
}
public class DataConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileIO fData1 = null;// ... appropriately obtained instance;
        FileIO fData2 = null;// ... appropriately obtained instance;
        ConsoleIO cData = null;// ... appropriately obtained instance;

        cData.write(fData2.read());
        fData1.write(cData.read());
    }
}
```

The client class uses only APIs of the devices. This will keep option of extending interface to implement new device wrapper (e.g. xml, stream etc)

Comment: That is defo a dao but I just feel like it is a ton of overkill. That said good answer on how to create a dao from file.